# Add JSON object from array of objects into another complex array of objects using JavaScript in efficient way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, momentjs

Input:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2018-03-31T15:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "Some Value"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-04-01T15:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "Some Value"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-04-02T15:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "Some Value"
  },
  so on...
]
```

Input complete JSON : https://api.myjson.com/bins/1e5qmn

Output:

```
[
  {
    "week": {
      "days": [
        {
          "date": 1,
          "day": "Sun",
          "formattedDate": "04/01(Sun)"
        },
        {
          "date": 2,
          "day": "Mon",
          "formattedDate": "04/02(Mon)"
        },
        so on...
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "week": {

    }
  },
  {
    "week": {

    }
  },
  so on...
]
```

Output complete JSON : https://api.myjson.com/bins/d8v4f

I am able to achieve Output using below code. I am using momentjs for formatting date (this is fine):

```
 var daysArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var dayOb = {
        date: '',
        day: '',
        formattedDate: '',
      };

      var date = results[i].date;

      dayOb.date = moment(date).date();
      dayOb.day = moment(date).format('ddd');
      dayOb.formattedDate = moment(date).format('MM/DD(ddd)');

      daysArray.push(dayOb);
    }

    var weeksArray = [];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(daysArray.length / 7); i++) {
      var weekOb = {
        week: {
          days: [],
        },
      };
      weeksArray.push(weekOb);
    }

    var nextStart = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < weeksArray.length; i++) {
      var count = 0;
      for (var j = nextStart; j < daysArray.length; j++) {
        count++;
        if (count < 8) {
          weeksArray[i].week['days'].push(daysArray[j]);
        } else {
          nextStart = j;
          break;
        }
      }
      count = 0;
    }
```

Working Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/r2og6c54/

**Question**: Is there any more efficient way to achieve this i.e. JavaScript native methods or reducing these too many for loops etc? Any suggestion is most welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Why is the output format so verbose? Each item is an object with a single key (`week`) which is another object with a single key (`days`)?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, that is sample. I added link of complete JSON output and input. Please check that

Comment: The fact that it's a sample doesn't change @EvanTrimboli's point. The output is indeed overly verbose. You could just have a nested array.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, that was requirement for UI. I need JSON data in this output format so that I can put it UI using AngularJS.

Comment: OK, fair point, although I don't exactly see how AngularJS benefits from having needless nested objects.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, Let's not go in that detail. My main point to how to write efficient JavaScript code for such complex examples. I know, we can make simple JSON output and serve it to UI. I hope you got my point. Actually that's why I used `efficient` word in question. Thanks!

Comment: Efficient code starts with efficient data structures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168024/discussion-between-vicjordan-and-robby-cornelissen).

Comment: Why not use javascript native array functions (map , reduce ) ?

Comment: **Downvoter** please mention the reason to downvote my question. Please don't do it bluntly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in vanilla JavaScript, without using moment.js:

```js
const input = [{
    "date": "2018-03-31T15:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "Some Value"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-04-01T15:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "Some Value"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-04-02T15:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "Some Value"
  }
];
const output = Array(Math.ceil(input.length / 7))
  .fill()
  .map((_, i) => i * 7)
  .map(i => input.slice(i, i + 7))
  .map(w => ({
    week: {
      days: w.map(d => new Date(d.date)).map(d => {
        const date = d.toLocaleDateString('en', {day: '2-digit'});
        const month = d.toLocaleDateString('en', {month: '2-digit'});
        const day = d.toLocaleDateString('en', {weekday: 'short'})
        return {date, day, formattedDate: `${month}/${date}(${day})`};
      })
    }
  }));

console.log(output)
```

If you want to also handle the `value`, you can do so as follows:

```
const output = Array(Math.ceil(input.length / 7))
  .fill()
  .map((_, i) => i * 7)
  .map(i => input.slice(i, i + 7))
  .map(w => ({
    week: {
      days: w.map(d => {
        const value = d.value;
        const date = new Date(d.date);
        const day = date.toLocaleDateString('en', {day: '2-digit'});
        const month = date.toLocaleDateString('en', {month: '2-digit'});
        const weekday = date.toLocaleDateString('en', {weekday: 'short'})
        return {day, weekday, formattedDate: `${month}/${day}(${weekday})`, value};
      })
    }
  }));
```

Comment: Shouldn't be hard. It's just a small addition to what I've already given you.

Comment: Please let me know, how. I am trying to check like this `const value = d.value;` but it returns `value = undefined`. I think `d` contains `date` only that's why I am getting undefined. Could you please update the snippet for how to get `value` key check and return if there is `some value` data available. Thank you!

Comment: It's because at that point `d` already contains a `Date` object due to the previous `map()` operation.

Comment: thanks a lot for this awesome piece of code. I am able to do change as per my second requirement. Thanks again.